# SSRS Divide by zero error

Tags: ssrs-2012, iif

I am getting NaN in 3 places in my SSRS report.  I believe it is because I am dividing by 0.  I am trying to find the average days for prescriptions on-time, late, and not filled.  The 3 expressions that I was given are below.  What and where would I need to insert the iif statement addressing the 0 issue.  I am new to this

```
=sum(iif(Fields!DaysDifference.Value >= -1 and Fields!DaysDifference.Value <= 1 and Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value <> 0, Fields!DaysDifference.Value,0))/
    sum(iif(Fields!DaysDifference.Value >= -1 and Fields!DaysDifference.Value <= 1 and Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value <> 0, 1,0))



=sum(iif(Fields!DaysDifference.Value > 1 and Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value <> 0, Fields!DaysDifference.Value,0))/
    sum(iif(Fields!DaysDifference.Value > 1 and Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value <> 0, 1,0))



=sum(iif(Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value = 0, Fields!DaysDifference.Value, 0))/
    sum(iif(Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value = 0, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Please calculate the AVG in tsql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 0, you should be dividing by your field:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value = 0, Fields!DaysDifference.Value, 0))/
    SUM(IIF(Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value = 0, 1, Fields!ActualNextFillDateKey.Value))
```